# JavaFx-- positioning components in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, javafx, scenebuilder

I used the drag and drop interface to put the components where I want them to be, but when the window is resized they lose their relative position. I have attached a screen shot of my hierarchy and of two windows to show how the components lose their position.

[Hierarchy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3w4jh2syb4ptxj/hierarchy.png?dl=0)
[Fullscreen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djgfe3fi1j003pw/fullscreen%20size.png?dl=0)

Comment: It would be great if you imported the images to your question, so there is no probability to get broken links in the future.

Comment: I can't find the second window image, there is only the fullscreen. Please, post your java code and fxml here, so we can help you. Consider making a MCVE : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I changed accounts and now I don't have enough reputation to import images or to put more than 2 links here. Here is the normal size images: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ufuut0zvjvcknf/normal%20size.png?dl=0   The only code I have at this point is the fxml generated by SceneBuilder. I will put that up in a moment. @henriqueor

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the AnchorPane to layout your components, you can set the Anchor Pane Constraints, like in the image below:

[image: Anchor Pane Constraints]

This way it doesn't matter if you resize the screen, the button will always stay 10px far from the AnchorPane's right border.

When you use the AnchorPane to place components on screen you are not going to have a relative positioning, You should use others containers to layout your application. Read more about how to use Layout Panes here: [Using Layout Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to study how to use [Layout Panes](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXLY). Dragging and dropping components results in absolute positioning, which really bad practice.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought absolute positioning will happen if I used just the pane, which in my case I didn't. I used (by drag and dropping) layout panes as you can see in my hierarchy. But it's acting like I did absolute position.

Comment: Drag and drop always leaves you with some absolute positioning. Study the layout panes first so you know how to use them, then go through you hierarchy and look for absolute values in the layout settings. You want as little as possible (preferably none).